# Is it possible to retrieve the the AWS Billing Account Id from an Account Id programmatically

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Is it possible to retrieve the Billing Account Id of an Account via the AWSSDK as shown in the screenshot below?

[image: Billing Account Id]

Comment: This is member account in your AWS Org?

Comment: This account is a member of an AWS Org. This is not the master org account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but I was able to achieve what I needed via the AWS Organization SDK.

```
using var awsClient = new AmazonOrganizationsClient(assumeRoleAwsCredentials, RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(regionEndpointSystemName));

try
{
    var response = await awsClient.DescribeOrganizationAsync(new DescribeOrganizationRequest());
    return response.Organization.MasterAccountId;
}
catch (AWSOrganizationsNotInUseException)
{
    return accountId;
}
```

Because accounts not in an organization will throw an `AWSOrganizationsNotInUseException` then the billing account Id must be itself.